# Accessing File property folderType

Tags: java, file-io

I notice that the File class has a property called folderType, but I cannot see anyway to get this String at run-time. Is there a way? Edit: perhaps it's not part of File.

When I rest my mouse over **file** in the fileIO.open

[image]

Comment: Where do you see that? I see no indication of that in the public API docs...

Comment: No such property exist in the File class.

Comment: Updated the question with where I see that.

Comment: Please check the following link and see if it's helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846078/jfilechoosershowsavedialog-cant-get-the-value-of-the-extension-file-chosen

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways one of them is this MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file)

and i think fileio is object of class Win32ShellFolder2,this has a public function getFolderType() as mentioned [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2.java#Win32ShellFolder2.getFolderType%28%29)

so you can use it like this i feel

```
fileIO.open(file).getFolderType()
```

Comment: What I really want to do is determine what type of file they are opening, based upon what I saw there, it seemed I could work with folderType.

Comment: you can use this new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file)

Comment: and this class "Win32ShellFolder2" has that property 

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2.java

Comment: @KiloJKilo Edited answer see if this serves your requirement

Answer (score 0):

The object you have there is a [`Win32ShellFolder2`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2.java), which is a subclass of [`ShellFolder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/awt/shell/ShellFolder.java), which is a subclass of java.io.File. `ShellFolder` defines a getter named `getFolderType()` which returns the folder type as a string.

So you could get the contents of the field like this:

```
file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
if (file instanceof ShellFolder) {
    ShellFolder sf = (ShellFolder)file;
    String folderType = sf.getFolderType();
```

`ShellFolder` and `Win32ShellFolder2` are in the package `sun.awt.shell`. This package isn't part of the standard Java API, so it could change from one JVM to another or from version of the JVM to another. See [With what should I replace sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder so I don't get compile warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994177/with-what-should-i-replace-sun-awt-shell-shellfolder-so-i-dont-get-compile-warn).